# Github and file Encoding diff

Tags: git, github, character-encoding

We're working on a Project using GitHub. Recently, we realised we've been using different encondings in both of our computers (one Branch with ISO8859-1 and the other with UTF-8). We finally managed to convert both branches to UTF-8. The conversión was done locally for each Branch (using "Save with Encodign" in Sublime) and then pushed to origin.

The problem is when running --diff or using web compare to check branches' mergeability. GitHub shows me lots of differences even though the files look the same, for example:

```
-#bit leds      = latB.2               //Leds de cámara 
-#bit ledsTris  = trisB.2              //Leds de cámara TRIS 
+#bit leds      = latB.2               //Leds de cámara 
+#bit ledsTris  = trisB.2              //Leds de cámara TRIS
```

Besides that, if I pull from different PCs, everything is UTF-8 encoded and looks OK in the editors (Sublime) (NO encoding issues). I don't understand why GitHub shows me these differences (there are thousands). What can I check or do before I have to go through an exaustive manual merge, cheking line by line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try passing --ignore-space-change to diff. Sublime might have changed tabs to spaces or line endings.

Comment: Forgot to mention… This is what I see using --diff in console:
-#bit leds      = latB.2               //Leds de cámara
-#bit ledsTris  = trisB.2              //Leds de cámara TRIS
+#bit leds      = latB.2               //Leds de c<E1>mara
+#bit ledsTris  = trisB.2              //Leds de c<E1>mara TRIS                       (It's showing difference in á!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that 'á' is encoded differently in UTF-8 and ISO8859-1 (and most likely on 2 bytes in UTF-8).
If you are able to rewrite the git history, then you may use git filter-branch --treefilter to change the encoding of all files for all commit with iconv:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'for f in $(find ./ -type f -name "*" |grep -v .git); do iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8 $f; done' HEAD
```